# Find variance given covariance of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

X and Y are two random variables with means of 1 and 3 and variances 3 and 7, respectively. W is a random variable which is a weighted average of X and Y, given by

W = aX+(1-a)Y, where a = 0.09. Find:

a) Mean of 11W

b) Variance of 11W, assuming X and Y are independent.

c) Variance of 11W, assuming Cov(X,Y)= -1.7

I have done the following for a) and b) (correct me if I'm wrong):

a) E(W)= (a)1+(1-a)3 = 2.82 hence 11E(W) = 11(2.82) = 31.02

b) Var(W)= (a)3+(1-a)7 = 6.64 hence 11Var(W) = 11(6.64) = 73.04

However, I am unsure how to go about doing c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value is right. And the variance of $11W$ is

$$Var(11W)=11^2\cdot Var(a\cdot bX+(1-a)\cdot Y)$$

If you factor out a constant, the constant has to be squared.

$$=11^2\cdot \left(Var(a\cdot X)+Var((1-a)\cdot Y)+2\cdot Cov(a\cdot X,(1-a)\cdot Y) \right)$$

Covariance is bilinear. That means, that $Cov(c\cdot X,b\cdot Y)=c\cdot b\cdot Cov(X,Y)$

$$=11^2\cdot \left(a^2\cdot Var(X)+(1-a)^2\cdot Var(Y)+2\cdot a\cdot (1-a)\cdot Cov(X,Y) \right)$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $Cov(X,Y)=0$

Comment: using your method for Var(11W), I got 803.44 when X and Y are independent. I then got 670.65 for Var(11W) when Cov(X,Y) -1.7. Are these correct? They seem a bit too high compared to the expected value.

Comment: @bizzey With the covariance I have the same result, without another. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11%5E2*%280.09%5E2*3%2B%281-0.09%29%5E2*7%2B2*0.09*+%281-0.09%29*%28-1.7%29%29) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11%5E2*%280.09%5E2*3%2B%281-0.09%29%5E2*7%29) the calculation. Maybe I have a typo somewhere. In general there is no direct relation between mean and variance. The variance measures the average squared distance.  The distances in between the values can be large, even when the mean is low.

Comment: @bizzey (cont.)  Side note: The [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) makes a direct connection between variance and expected value.